# How to replace inline comment a full-line comment for Fortran file

Tags: vim, editor, atom-editor

I am handling several large `Fortran` code files and I encounter a tricky problem, which is I want to make inline comment a full-line comment. Clearly it is absurd to do it manually line by line. All characters following an exclamation mark, `!`, except in a character string, are commentary, and are ignored by the compiler.

That is to say change

```
 x = 9 !initialize x
```

to

```
 x = 9
 !initialize x
```

That would be great if it can be implemented via `vim` or `atom`.

Code example `ex.f90`

```
subroutine sample_photon(e0,zz,sgam,ierr)
  use EBL_fit
  use constants
  use user_variables, only : ethr,model
  use internal, only : debug
  implicit none
  integer ierr,nrej,nrejmax,nrenorm
  real(kind=8) e0,zz,sgam,de,emin,emin0 &
  ,etrans1,etrans2,aw1,aw2,aw3,gb,gb0,gbmax,gbnorm,rrr,gnorm1,gnorm2,gnorm3
  real(kind=8) psran,sigpair,w_EBL_density

  de=4.d0*e0
  emin0=ame**2/e0                  ! minimal required energy for EBL photon
  if (emin0.ge.eirmax) then        ! wrong kinematics
!!!     write(*,*)'photon:',emin0,eirmax,e0
     ierr=1
     return
  end if

  nrej=0
  nrejmax=3000                     ! user-defined limit on the N of rejections
  nrenorm=0
  gbmax=0.d0
  gbnorm=2.5d0                      ! normalization factor for rejection

  etrans1=1.d-6                    ! parameters for 'proposal function'
  etrans2=eirmin*(1.d0+zz)**1.25

! partial weights for different energy intervals for 'proposal function

! sample emin (= sgam/de) according to the 'proposal function';
! define 'rejection function' ( gb = f(emin) / f_proposal(emin) )


  sgam=emin*de                 ! c.m. energy for gamma-gamma interaction
  gb=w_EBL_density(emin,zz)*sigpair(sgam)*emin/gb0

!  if (gb.gt.1.d0.and.nrenorm.eq.0) write(*,*)'sample_cmb(photon): gb=' &
!  ,gb,nrenorm,emin,emin0,emin0/etrans2  !/1.d3

  if (psran().gt.gb) then       ! rejection
     nrej=nrej+1                ! total number of rejections for current sampling
     gbmax=max(gbmax,gb)        ! maximal value for rejection function
     if(nrej.gt.nrejmax)then    ! too many rejections
      if(gbmax.le.0.d0)then     ! wrong kinematics
       write(*,*)'photon: gbmax=0!!!'
       ierr=1
       return
      else
!       write(*,*)'nrej(gamma)>nrejmax',nrej,emin0/etrans2,nrenorm,e0/1.d12,gbmax
       gbnorm=gbnorm*gbmax*2.d0 ! change normalization for the rejection function
       gbmax=0.d0
       nrenorm=nrenorm+1
       nrej=0
      endif
     endif
     goto 1                     ! new try
  end if

end subroutine sample_photon
```

Comment: Well you can start with `:%s/!/\r!/g`, but that will separate consecutive `!` to separate lines, as well as not accounting for strings.

Comment: Best regex I've come up with will only do a newline if the `!` is not preceeded by "write", and consecutive `!` will stick together.  It's definitely not perfect, but if you want perfect, you'll need something that actually parses fortran.  `:%s/\(write.*\)\@<!\(!\+\)/\r\2/g`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's build this gradually, and start with a simple substitution that prepends a newline (`\r`) to any sequence of comment prefixes (`!`):

```
:%substitute/!\+.*$/\r&/
```

This leaves behind trailing whitespace. We can match that as well, and use a *capture group* (`\(...\)`) for the actual comment. This removes the whitespace:

```
:%substitute/\s*\(!\+.*$\)/\r\1/
```

But it still matches comments at the start of a line, and introduces an additional empty line in front. We can add a *lookbehind assertion* that the line must not start with a `!`, but this now gets ugly:

```
:%substitute/^\%(^[^!].*\)\@=.*\zs\s*\(!\+.*$\)/\r\1/
```

Instead, it's easier to use another Vim command, `:global` (or its inverted sister `:vglobal`), to only match lines not starting with `!`, and then apply the `:substitute` there:

```
:%vglobal/^!/substitute/\s*\(!\+.*$\)/\r\1/
```

The final requirement is that exclamation marks within strings should be kept. This would add another regular expression, and integrating it into the overall match would be really hard, and could probably be only done approximately. Fortunately, with syntax highlighting, Vim already knows what is a Fortran string!

My [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602) has (among others) a `:SubstituteIf` / `:SubstituteUnless` combo that can do substitutions only if a condition is true / false. The library it depends on provides a wrapper around `synIdAttr()` that makes it easy to define a predicate for Fortran strings:

```
function! IsFortranString()
    return ingo#syntaxitem#IsOnSyntax(getpos('.'), '^fortranString')
endfunction
```

We then only need to replace `:substitute` with `:SubstituteUnless` + predicate:

```
:%vglobal/^!/SubstituteUnless/\s*\(!\+.*$\)/\r\1/ IsFortranString()
```

The same can also be achieved without the plugin (using `:help sub-replace-special` and `synstack()` / `synIdAttr()`), but it'd be more complex.

Comment: You could write a simple Fortran code to read the file line by line and rewrite it as you like,  I have a folder called rerite which contains fortran codes to rerite something...